# Using block as sub-menu

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

Is there any module to put blocks under menu items? I will use it to create mega menu. I mean something to generate this code:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="...">Item</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
     <div class="block">...</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

best one out there from my experience would be: http://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu --- it should take you no longer than 15 minutes to figure out how it works. you'll still need to do some css width adjustments to get it working with your own layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think [menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) is what you want.

Another suggestion is use php filter in block content and try something like

```
<?php
 $menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-your-custom-menu-name');
 print theme('links__menu_your_custom_menu_name', array('links' => $menu));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [TB mega menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) or [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) is the answer for your question. It provides you better control on menus.

Hope it is what you need.